# Resize an image by dragging and dropping in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Ss there anyway to select a section of an image in Photoshop and drag it to resize. You can do this in Microsoft Word and other programs, so there must be way to drag and resize in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Cooper is correct but just wanted to make one point explicit.  The only thing that was missing was after you select your image, you must click (or double click) on the image or it will just change the selection without actualy affecting the underlying image.  Once you click it seems to grab the image.

Comment: You should mark his answer correct then and either comment on his answer, ask him to add it to his answer, or edit his answer yourself. He answered your question correctly, not you.

Answer (score 8):

Use the marquee tool (hotkey M) to select the portion of the image you want to resize, then use the Transformation tool hotkey: Ctrl+T (somewhere in the edit menu, but I always use hotkeys). This will bring up the transformation tools you want. When you are done, press Enter, or the check button on the option bar along the top.

Also, if you want the section you are resizing to not deform or stretch, hold down Shift while resizing will constrain the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: this seems to resize the selection (the dotted line) but not my image.  any suggestions?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have posted another answer giving a solution to resizing the image the way you wanted.

Comment: You should put both answers into a single one instead of doing 2.

Comment: I'm not sure your two answers are mutually exclusive.  The image can't exceed the canvas, so that part of your other answer is needed.  Once the canvas is large enough, can't you select the entire image and do what you describe here?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, you want to edit the entire image. That was unclear to me when I posted my first answer.

To resize an entire image, there is no way (that I know of) to do that graphically.

The way to do it, though is with the two menu items `Image > Image Size` and `Image > Canvas Size`. `Image Size` will change the size of the image, and you have to put it a new dimension either in pixels, inches, percent, or a few other units. `Canvas Size` will change the size of the canvas, without changing the image it self. So your art won't change, but you will have more room to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the image if you would like to resize it within the layer. Select the image and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and resize the image and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply your changes to the image.